# Como recibe el parametro?

Tags: javascript

Cuando tengo lo siguiente:

```
var anyn = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

function hacerAlgo(elemento) {

console.log(elemento)

}

anyn.forEach(hacerAlgo);
```

Sé que funciona así ,pero quiero saber por qué y como se le llama a esto , me gustarían mas ejemplos y documentación, me refiero a la parte de:

```
anyn.forEach(hacerAlgo);
```

Hasta donde yo sé una función para recibir un parametro debe ser llamada en  este caso:

```
hacerAlgo(parametro);
```

pero aca nunca se hace eso.. entonces?

según lo que he investigado creo que funciona como solo una ***referencia***, osea el `forEach` envia cada uno de los elementos del `array` y la función `hacerAlgo`, es como la referencia a la que se le pasaran por parametros, pero me gustarian mas ejemplos aparte de `forEach`, y si estoy en lo correcto o no.

Comment: Te recomiendo revises [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach) encontraras todo lo que necesitas saber este método, Saludos!! ;))...

Answer (score 1):

El forEach es un método que aplica a los arreglos. Permite iterar los elementos de un arreglo.

Para más información puedes consultar:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forEach.asp

Estas en lo correcto parcialmente, es una función que aplica al array. En ese sentido recibe parámetros.

Todos los objetos en JavaScript provienen de Object; todos los objetos heredan métodos y propiedades de Object.prototype, aunque pueden ser sobrecargados (excepto un Object con una propiedad null, p.e. Object.create(null)). Por ejemplo, otros prototipos de los constructores sobrecargan la propiedad del constructor y proporcionan su propio método toString(). Los cambios hechos al objeto prototipo Object se propagan a todos los objetos a menos que las propiedades y métodos sujetos a dichos cambios sean sobrecargados aún más a lo largo de la cadena del prototipo.

Saludos,

Answer (score 1):

Tal como la [documentacion](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/forEach) lo indica la propiedad de un Object.forEach del tipo `Array` hace lo siguiente :

```
arr.forEach(function callback(currentValue, index, array) {

});
```

Donde :

> **currentValue**
>       El elemento actual siendo procesado en el array.
>
> **index**
>   El índice del elemento actual siendo procesado en el array.
>
> **array**
>   El arreglo en el que forEach esta siendo aplicado.
>
> **callback**
>   Función a ejecutar por cada elemento, que recibe tres argumentos

- Array : `var anyn = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`
- Index : Indice del elemento actual de tu array (0,1,2,3....) hasta el `legth-1` de tu coleccion.
- currentValue : el valor del elemento en la iteracion `anyn[index]` ej : `anyn[0] = 1`.

Entonces esto :

```js
var anyn = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

function hacerAlgo(elemento) {

console.log(elemento)

}

anyn.forEach(hacerAlgo);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Es igual a esto :

```js
var anyn = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

function hacerAlgo(elemento, index, array) {

console.log(array[index])

}

anyn.forEach(hacerAlgo);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Queriendo decir que por defecto y sin necesidad de especificar los parametros que la funcion espera, los interpreta de igual manera.

Answer (score 0):

Si hubiese que hacer una definición de foreach, se podría hacer con un código como este:

```js
var array = {
    forEach : function (callback){
      for (let i = 0; i < this.elements.length; i++){
          callback(this.elements[i], i, this.elements);
      }
    },
    elements : [],
    set : function (theArray){
      this.elements = theArray;
    }
};

//console.log(array);

// definir array
var miArray = [1,2,3,4,5];

// esto lo hago para que el ejemplo sea similar :P 
// pero imagina que aquí se hace lo mismo que arriba :)
array.set([1,2,3,4,5]);

// llamar foreach
array.forEach(function (element){ 
    element += 1;
});

miArray.forEach(function (element){ 
    element += 1; 
});

// esto sucede por que se pasan por valor
console.log("ejemplo 1", array.elements, miArray);

// para que funciones debes usar el tercer parametro
// llamar foreach
array.forEach(function (currentValue, index, arr){ 
    arr[index] += 1;
});

miArray.forEach(function (currentValue, index, arr){ 
    arr[index] += 1;
});

// ahora si funciona
console.log("ejemplo 2", array.elements, miArray);
```

El foreach es un método de arrays, que funciona como el ejemplo que te he adjuntado (me atrevería a decir que igual). La diferencia es que cuando lo haces con corchetes "[]" se crea un objeto propio del lenguaje y se llaman a métodos nativos implementados por el navegador web (o el interprete de js que uses).

Este tipo de funciones se llaman [callbacks o retrollamadas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(inform%C3%A1tica)) y existen en la mayoría de los lenguajes de programación.

> Una devolución de llamada o retrollamada (en inglés: callback) es una función "A" que se usa como argumento de otra función "B". Cuando se llama a "B", ésta ejecuta "A". Para conseguirlo, usualmente lo que se pasa a "B" es el puntero a "A".

Adicionalmente, la explicación de por que no funciona el "ejemplo 1" es por que los valores del array que se envían al callback se hacen como valores y no como [referencias](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referencia_(inform%C3%A1tica)) (por que son primitivos). Esto quiere decir que no se modifica el valor "original" sino que se modifica una copia temporal que el lenguaje crea para el ámbito de la función. Puedes ver esto en la [documentación de funciones](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions):

> Primitive parameters (such as a number) are passed to functions by value; the value is passed to the function, but if the function changes the value of the parameter, this change is not reflected globally or in the calling function.